# I am getting below nextjs serverless deployment error(running npx serverless)

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, next.js, serverless, aws-serverless

[image]

Always getting this error while the deployment of serverless nextjs and my serverless config is below

```
sprinkle:
  component: "@sls-next/serverless-component@1.19.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had also same error while deploying nextjs app.
I just remove version name from `@sls-next/serverless-component@1.19.0` and the error was gone.
here is my nextjs.config code

```
nextjsapp:
  component: "@sls-next/serverless-component"
  inputs:
    timeout:
      defaultLambda: 30
      apiLambda: 30
      imageLambda: 30
```